# Sql design with domain metadata: two tables (one to one) or one table representing different kinds of data?

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design

I have an invoice table.

```
Invoices
--------
id
invoicenum
description
amount
rowversion
```

I need to attach metadata to this table, such as business unit location, last modified by, last modified on, and security access code.

```
InvoiceMetadata
---------------
id
BU
User
Date
AccessCode
rowversion
```

I now have two options. I can just tack these fields onto my Invoices table, or I can create a separate table that logically contains this information.

What factors do I need to consider to make an intelligent decision? My inner programmer says I need to create two tables. My inner DBA says I need to make one. My inner project manager says I need to know what the payoffs are for both options. It is this last inner voice I need help with.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a third order form relational database ( one that is efficient and can be queried effectively) put the data in another table. If I understand the columns in  InvoiceMetadata there is one record (per customer) for many invoices per customer. If all the columns reappear (and are different) for every invoice then put it in the same invoice table - otherwise create a second table linked perhaps by a customer ID.